# Manhua where a guy needs to be killed to fulfil a karmic destiny

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation, cultivation

A Chinese manhua where a guy who died from overworking is reincarnated in a world with cultivators, and has a title like 'kill me so I can reincarnate'. He's reincarnated in an isekai as karmic retribution, except he didn't fulfil a particular criteria so he has to be killed again. He is pulled along on an adventure with the cultivator.